# Cue with red dot

Tags: support, vote-to-close

My review queue "Close Votes" is marked with a red dot. What does that mean? I could not find the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means there are relatively many questions in the Close Votes review queue (compared to normal Philosophy.SE levels). 50, that's quite a lot for a site this size.

More details on Meta Stack Exchange: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/295232)